# How do I create a stand alone program or application for windows using either 'C' or 'C++'

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know just how I can turn any code I write in either 'C' or 'C++' into an actual stand alone application or program I can run on windows without having to compile and run through visual studio. EX: like if I wanted to make a new type of calculator that would do complex math problems and use it without having to boot up VS all the time?

Comment: Visual Studio produces executables; that's what it does.

Comment: I enjoy this question. In my mind it translates to: How do I write a real program instead of an app I can run in VS2013.

Comment: I understand what VS does, but my question is how do I use the program I wrote without having to run it through VS?

Comment: Find the executable it produced, and run it. By default it will be in a sub-folder of your project folder (e.g. Win32\Release).

Comment: Are you talking about not using the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your version of Visual Studio, but every time you build or execute your program Visual Studio will build an executable(.exe). You can copy and share this executable.

Depending on the stuff you use in this executable you might need to share libraries (DLL's) or change your linking options. It is possible to include all the extra tools you use in your application by instructing the linker to include them. This is called a static link. This makes your executable a lot larger. The other option would be a dynamic link, this would require the recipient of your application to have the same libraries (DLL's) as you had while developing your calculator. This would make your application a lot smaller, but depending on those DLL's.

Comment: I'm using VS 2012, and just where would the actual executable file be stored, I go to file directory of where I save my programs, but each one wants to bring up VS, which would be the correct one that would allow me to run the program outside of VS?

Comment: @ChrisHoward  I recall you have a Debug and a Release folder inside your project folder. Look for an .exe file there. Do a save and a "Build" if you can't find it.

Comment: it was in the debug file, I also did not see nor find a Release folder.

Comment: @ChrisHoward The debug folder contains non-optimised builds. The Released folder contains more reasonable .exes if you want share them. You can easily change the build type with a few clicks.

Answer (score -3):

Download a copy of [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and use it to install an opensource tools environment for C/C++. You will need as a minimum, a copy of gcc, and editor if you don't already have one, and bash/terminal or similar (you can also use cmd.exe, but the bash environment is much better.)

You can then create whatever programs you like without using Visual Studio. Welcome to the dark side...

Comment: Note to down voters. The question was "run on windows __without having to compile and run through visual studio.__"

cygwin/gcc lets you do this - and is a free and portable alternative to Visual Studio. Yes there's a learning curve - but if the objective is to teach students to master all the necessary elements of programming, it's often better to start with simple command line programs, and then introduce IDE's.